# Identifying 1st column length check in 1st column

Tags: awk

Can anyone help me in identifying the 1st column's length. I need to check if 1st column's length is greater than 10? If that is true, I need to move the records into a text file.

```
**ABC239487SAN**|239487| - 13

**ABC23948SAN**|239489| -12

**ABC990SAN**|99072| -10

**ABC990SAN**|99072| -10

**ABC990SAN**|99076| -10

**ABC990SAN**|99076| -10
```

Comment: OP, please use code tags for sample Inputs and sample outputs in your posts as per forum rules, thank you. Keep learning and keep sharing, cheers !!

Answer (score 2):

```
awk -F'|' 'length($1)>10' infile > outfile
```

Comment: as simple as that

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try following `awk` and let me know if this helps.

```
awk -F"|" '{if(length($1)>=10){print $0,length($1) > "output_file"}}'  Input_file
OR
awk -F"|" '{printf("%s%s",length($1)>=10?$0"," length($1):"",RS)}'  Input_file > output_file
```

Above code will make field separator as `|` of each line then it will check if 1st field length is greater or equal to `10` if yes then it will print current line and 1st field's length to the output file.

Comment: you can move `if` out of the statement `length($1)>=10{...}`, more `awk`ish that way.